# jquery scrollTop slideDown can't stop repeat

Tags: jquery, css, slidedown

I've searched in many posts on stackoverflow but didn't find my solution.

After scrolling down 200px, I want to bring up a menu bar, no problem.
I want it to appear with a slideDown.

The problem is that after scrolling down under 200px, each time I scroll down again, the slideDown() slides again, and I wand it to slideDown only once the first time it exceeds 200px down.

Here is my jQuery code :

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
delta = 5;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();
  if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
      return;

  //initialisation div caché :
  $('#menu-container-mini').css("display", "none");

  if (st > lastScrollTop){
    // scrolling down :
    console.log('scroll down'+st);
    if(st>200){
      // Scrolling down après 150px
      console.log('scroll down st>150 : '+st);

      // This condition isn't respected
      // Each time I scroll down, the slideDown starts again :


      if($('#menu-container-mini').css('display')=='none')
      {
        $('#menu-container-mini').slideDown('slow').css("display", "block");
      }

    }
  }
  lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

Thanks a lot for help !

Comment: Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net/ ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to do it one time, you can create a boolean and set it initially to false. Then once you scroll past 200 pixels, check your variable if it's false, and if it is, call your slideDown() and then set your variable to true.

Then if you want you can set your variable back to false once you scroll up high enough

*edit: I found the error, every time you scroll you are calling

```
//initialisation div caché :
 $('#menu-container-mini').css("display", "none");
```

Which is why your popup goes away. Move that line above your $(window).scroll function

Comment: even with a boolean, it continues to repeat during scrolling down. Here is a jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nonoseki/8g91pdf8/

Comment: thanks a lot ! I wrote this instruction in bad place. Hope to see this mistake next time. THANKS !

Comment: @Nonoseki No problem! Please take the time to mark my answer as correct, thanks!